# Does the GameBoy have provisions to run in a low/lower power mode, e.g. when games are paused?

Tags: gameboy

When paused some Gameboy games:

1. Continue with moving visuals (to some degree),
2. Continue with music.
3. Get silent and have a static image only:

- either last frame frozen, maybe combined with a "Paused" overlay,
- or feature a custom static Pause screen.

As this was a portable console and battery life limited I ask myself:

- Did the GameBoy more or less run in an endless processing loop and consumed the same energy regardless where in gameplay?
- Or did the GameBoy provide a low power mode for less active gameplay, like "Inventory Screens" or "Pause screens" from which a key press functioned as a CPU interrupt to continue at full throttle again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely possible to program your game in a way that reduces power consumption. [This guide](https://gbdev.io/pandocs/Reducing_Power_Consumption.html) contains some good examples. One of the more notable examples is to use the `halt` CPU instruction when waiting for things like VBlank.

Comment: Good resource you pointed me to. Thanks for the answer!